# How to relogin in the git

Tags: git

I have new account on `some_url_git` and old account is removed. How can I re-login?

When I try in command line example :

`git fetch`

Then I have:

> remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier *WebProject* does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.
>
> fatal: repository 'some_url_git ' not found

Comment: Can you add a more accurate example URL? What is the git hosting service you use? How do you connect? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: this git url is on some server inside the comany and it not important.  I found the solution in  windows credential manager. I changed user github entry under control panel > user accounts > credential manager > Windows credentials > Generic credentials

Comment: Good! I’m glad you found a solution. May you add an answer or delete the question?

Comment: does anyone has an idea what to do in macOS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In  the windows credential manager need change user github entry under control panel > user accounts > credential manager > Windows credentials > Generic credentials

Comment: I will say, thanks for pointing me in the direction, to allow re-login, for me, I had to delete the 'Github' credential - this allowed me to log in again.

Comment: What if we have mac?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps

```
git config --global user.name "git hub user name "
git config --global user.email "git hub email "
```

then you need to check credential are added or not for that you need to run below commands

```
git config user.name --> it will throw your git hub user name 
git config user.email --> it will trow your git hub email
```

Comment: The user.name and user.email settings in git have nothing to do with authentication to different git servers.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the user/password entries in `.git/config` or `~/.gitconfig` or `~/.git-credentials`

and I was asked to re-login when I did the `git push` next.

That was what worked for me on Linux.